# Is it possible to place a marker on the scrollbar of FlowDocumentReader?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar, flowdocumentreader

I have two questions with regard to the scrollbar of FlowDocumentReader:

1. In WPF, is it possible to place a marker on the scrollbar of FlowDocumentReader? I want to show search result of certain strings in the FlowDocument.
2. If the answer to the first question is "no", then is it possible to get the location of the thumb of the scrollbar, which belongs to the FlowDocumentReader?  So that I can draw a small line on the scrollbar to show the search results?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the FlowDocumentReader. But you can do such thing using ScrollViewer. You can place your control inside an scroll viewer and make it do the scrolling part.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336441/how-to-scroll-wpf-scrollviewers-content-to-specific-location) might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I kinda want to use the FlowDocumentReader because it has a built-in search function, which can keep search the same string in the flow document. I don't know how to build that function by myself yet.