# How to scroll ScrollViewer to the specific RadioButton location

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

**xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1" CanContentScroll="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1" Content="RadioButton1" GroupName="MyGroup" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="30"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton2" Content="RadioButton2" GroupName="MyGroup" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="30"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton3" Content="RadioButton3" GroupName="MyGroup" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="30"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton4" Content="RadioButton4" GroupName="MyGroup" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="30"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton5" Content="RadioButton5" GroupName="MyGroup" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="30"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton6" Content="RadioButton6" GroupName="MyGroup" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="30"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton7" Content="RadioButton7" GroupName="MyGroup" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="30"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton8" Content="RadioButton8" GroupName="MyGroup" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="30"/>
    </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

**vb.net**

```
Class MainWindow 
Private Sub RadioButton5_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles RadioButton5.Checked
    ScrollViewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0)
End Sub
End Class
```

If you click `RadioButton5` you will see that `ScrollViewer1` scrolls to the zero position. So, the above codes work great.

I want `ScrollViewer1` to scroll to the `RadioButton3` position when **The User** clicks `RadioButton8`.

The answer from **Robert Levy** looks good but I don't understand how to implement **Robert Levy**'s answer here: [How to scroll WPF ScrollViewer's content to specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336441/how-to-scroll-wpf-scrollviewers-content-to-specific-location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scroll the button to be under the mouse:
You can get the position of the button relative to the mouse with

```
Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(RadioButton5);
```

And then scroll to the button with

```
ScrollViewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(ScrollViewer1.VerticalOffset - position.Y);
```

If I understand you correctly you wand to scroll the button to be on top of the list. You could reach this by

```
Point point = ScrollViewer1.TranslatePoint(new Point(), RadioButton5);
ScrollViewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(ScrollViewer1.VerticalOffset - point.Y);
```

I hope this is what you tried to do.

Comment: Do you try to bring the button on top of the ScrollVierwer?